# When summing a value calculated by multiplying other values, the value is included as a string, however when directly referenced it behaves as a value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am fairly new to Excel and only using it for a hobby, however I have noticed that when I attempt to add an entire column of values together, there is one value that is not included in the addition. It is also the only 'non-defined' value of the column (i.e. it is calculated using a formula rather than being inputted directly). When I go to edit the formula I see that the value in question (in the below screenshot 24.99), it seems to be a string given the speech marks either side of it, hence why it isn't in the addition.

[image: row of values in the column]
[image: list of relevant values]

I am confused as when I reference only that value in a sum, the value is included in the sum, as seen below:

[image: number used as value]

Before it is suggested, I have experimented with using different data types for the value in the cell, including 'Currency', which is what the rest of the cells in the column are, as well as 'Number', 'Accounting', and 'General'. One thing that is strange is that the £ symbol never appears at the front of the number, no matter what data type it's casted as.

For those that are curious, the formula that is used to get the number in the cell B9 is below, where H13 is a number in the form 'Currency', and J13 is a number in the form 'General'.

`=IMPRODUCT(H13,J13)`

Comment: to sum an imaginary number .. you need to use `IMSUM()` , `SUM()` seems to only deal with real number

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. Is there a way for the £ symbol to be there as with all the other cells do you know?

Comment: r-click > format cell >try : currency

Comment: Isn't guideline/practice to accept an answer that has been submitted if it works for O.P,? The comment above (after which pt. OP appears to have 'disappeared' from this thread) fixes a short-term issue within the Q, but a) proposal was not submitted; b) underlying question (one can only guess,  concerned the following statement "I am confused as when I reference only that value in a sum, the value is included in the sum, as seen below"....  Dismayed when effort goes into creating a soln, writing it up, etc. and OP doesn't even look at it (I can only surmise given lack of comment/up /down vote)

Answer (score 1):

Per [this](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2018/07/18/excel-convert-text-to-number/) link, a common way to convert text formatted numbers to, well, 'numbers' is to apply a mathematical operation (e.g. if you have ="100", multiplying by 1 will yield 100 - see screenshot)...

**Cell constituents**

[image: 1a) Cell constituents: toggle with CTRL + `]

**Result**

[image: Results]

See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885) for Microsoft's own words *"Numbers that are stored as text can cause unexpected results."*.

In your example (which I've successfully replicated to aide this soln. - see below), taking 0-B9 (per below screenshot, courtesy your Q above) yields -24.99 in this case as Excel interprets cell B9 as an operand, upon which -1x (as an operation) is applied:

[image: Per Q provided by @TYG]

Put another way, you can yield exactly the same (or rather, 'anticipated') result via the summation formula as follows:

[image: Impact of mathematical operations on text formatted cells]

Included in the above figure is a depiction of how I have become familiarised with this 'conversion via mathematical operation' trick: it shows how taking 0 + False = 0 (or rather, per the depiction above, 0 + True = 1).

### Simple example

Try the following to convince yourself:

Enter ="0", ="1", and ="2" in cells A1:A3 respectively.  In the adjacent column/cells (B1:B3), enter =1-A1/A2/A3 as the case may be, i.e.:

[image: Simple example - precursor]

**Results**

[image: Simple example - results]

### Advanced example

Now go ahead and enter (per cell) 3 a's followed by 'b' and 'c' (lowercase) in cells A1:A5. In cell B1 enter the formula "=A1:a5 = "a" (assuming you have Office 365, else use 'Ctrl+shift+enter').  This will return an array of corresponding 'True' and 'False' values for any character (col A) that satisfies the condition '="a"', *videlicit*:

[image: Array implementation of mathematical operation conversion - Part 1]

Of course, summing column B would be futile (well, it returns 0):

[image: Array implementation of mathematical operation conversion - Part 2]

However, applying an innocuous mathematical operation '1 *' makes all the difference in the world:  you now have an elegant (but time / calculation expensive) way to calculate the count of cells that satisfy the criteria '="a"' - in this case, 3!

[image: Array implementation of mathematical operation conversion - Results A]

Of course, the same could be achieved using any 'neutral' calculation - for instance, adapting the apparent anomaly you've stumbled upon, using sum(0+(A1:A5 = "a") yields the self-same count of 3 ☺

[image: Array implementation of mathematical operation conversion - Results B]

i.e.

[image: Array implementation of mathematical operation conversion - Results B]

Trust this delineates/clarifies (with sufficient detail) the reason why a straight summation (which lack any 'special' operations in its own right) does not include text values, where as taking 0-B9 (per your Q) does (i.e. via the implicit 0-1*B9 operand with respect to B9).

Answer (score 0):

> using different data types for the value in the cell, including 'Currency'

What you changed is the number format, not data type.
It's an important difference in Excel, you can change format of cells containing numbers, however if a cell contains text - regardless of it actually represents a number - changing number format will not affect it.

> =IMPRODUCT(H13,J13)

This function is used to multiply complex numbers. You could use `=H13*J13`

> when I reference only that value

Functions taking multiple values (SUM, AVERAGE, MIN...) are designed everything not stored as number.
On the other side, if you explicitly include text in a calculation, Excel will try to convert it (e.g. 1 + "9" = 10).

That's what happens in your example too, you don't just include your string in SUM, but first it's added to 0.